# Fetch messages with discord.js V12 doesn't work for me. [Discord.js V12]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

As you can read on my title, I can't fetch messages with discord.js.

In discord.js v11 I used this :

```js
var bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.on('ready', () => {
  bot.channels.get(channelID).fetchMessages({ around: messageID, limit: 1 })
    .then(async msg => {
      //my code here 
    });
});
```

Id discord.js v12 it should be like this :

```js
var bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.on('ready', () => {
  bot.channels.cache.get(channelID).messages.fetch({ around: messageID, limit: 1 })
    .then(async msg => {
      //my code here 
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work for me..

Can you please help me for this ? 
May be with an other alternative.

Thank you for your help !

EDIT 1 : 
It return : 
`(node:17184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined`

Comment: Could you please explain what _"doesn't work"_? What do you expect to see? What are you actually seeing? Are there any reported error messages?

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited my topic.

Comment: You shouldn't use the var keyword; prefer const and let instead.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm sorry, I figure it out that my code was correct, but I do not know why that doesn't worked when I tried it ..
I literally wrote this:

```js
bot.channels.cache.get('ChannelID').messages.fetch({ around: 'messageID', limit: 1 })

.then(async msg => {

 //my code here
})
```

That's the same shit, I lost hours for that '-'

Anyway, sorry for the lost of your time to.

I'll delete this.

Comment: The channel didn't exist in your bot's cache before. Either you were using a number rather than a string (all Snowflake IDs must be strings), the channel really didn't exist, or the ID was incorrect. Small suggestion: use `.fetch('messageID')` instead of bothering with options, and it'll give you your message as if v11.

Answer (score 1):

discord.js v12 doesnt use `client.channels.cache.get(id)`
but  `client.channels.resolve(id)`
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=resolve

I don't quite understand what you mean by messages property, as channel doesnt have any like that in documentation. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel

Comment: `client.channels.cache.get(id)` works perfectly fine in v12. The `cache` property of a Manager is a Collection which extend Maps, inheriting `Map#get()`. Both should return the same value (the former uses the latter) in this specific case. Also, the basic Channel structure doesn't have a `messages` property, but a TextChannel does ([here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=messages)).